# How do I remove leading and trailing spaces AND underscores?

Tags: shell-script

I have the spaces part working but is there a quick way to tag the underscores removal to it?

```
echo \"" & [applescript string input] & "\" | xargs
```

**Context:**

Applescript:

```
on trim(i)
    return (do shell script "echo \"" & i & "\" | xargs")
end trim

set input to "  _someString "
set output to trim(input)
```

- Current output: "_some_String", as expected.
- Desired output: "some_String"

Comment: What's the context you're doing this in? Where does the input come from, and what do you want to do with it? I'm also not sure what you're doing here in the command shown; `xargs` would remove whitespace in the input, but you're giving it a quoted string, and it doesn't remove the whitespace inside the quotes...

Answer (score 1):

Removing leading and trailing whitespace characters and underscores can be done with `sed` with:

```
sed 's/^[_[:space:]]*//; s/[_[:space:]]*$//'
```

Which would turn:

```
  _foo_bar_
_ _ _ x  y _ _
```

Into:

```
foo_bar
x  y
```

In any case, please refrain from using `xargs` to do text processing. `xargs` processes its input in a very special way which is hardly ever what you want (splits on some whitespace characters the list of which varies with the implementation, handles quotes and backslash in its own unique way, some implementations treat some characters like `_` as meaning end of input, some choke on non-text, some have ridiculously low limit on line length or number of arguments...), and when not given any command, runs `echo` by default which is notoriously broken and unportable, and also spawning one process for each line of output (and executing the standalone `echo` utility in each).

Some `sed` implementations would also choke on non-text input or too-long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -ne '.subst(:global, / ^  <[\s_]>*  | <[_\s]>* $ /).put;'  

#OR

raku -pe '.=subst(:global, / ^  <[\s_]>*  | <[_\s]>* $ /);'
```

OR

```
raku -ne 'put S:g/ ^ <[\s_]>* | <[_\s]>* $ //;' 

#OR

raku -pe 's/ ^ <[\s_]>* | <[_\s]>* $ //;'
```

The Raku code above uses a custom character class `<[_\s]>` created by the `<[`…`]>` markers. Raku's `|` pipe operator **OR**s based upon Longest Token Matching (LTM), which doesn't require special ordering of arguments (use `||` in Raku to get Perl's "first-matching" semantics).

(Thanks to @Stéphane_Chazelas for the examples below).

Sample Input:

```
_Some String
  _foo_bar_
 _ _ x  y _ _
```

Sample Output:

```
Some String
foo_bar
x  y
```

https://raku.org